# JQuery Submit button does not work Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying everything to make my webpage smoother.  The thing is, I've tried to make a JQuery submit and now, the button does not do anything when pressed.

Here is my code:

`The form:`

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="author-thumb">
        <img src="{{ Auth::user()->getFirstMediaUrl('pps') ? Auth::user()->getFirstMediaUrl('pps')  : '/img/ava_10.jpg' }}" width="36" height="36" alt="author">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group with-icon label-floating is-empty">
        <label class="control-label">Share what you are thinking here...</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="add-options-message">
        <a href="#" class="options-message" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"   data-original-title="ADD PHOTOS">
            <svg class="olymp-camera-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-header-photo"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#olymp-camera-icon"></use></svg>
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md-2" id="ajaxSubmit">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`The controller:`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $post->username = Auth::user()->username;
    $post->author = Auth::user()->name;
    $post->content = $request->content;
    $post->save();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);
}
```

`The route:`

```
Route::post('/post', [

'uses' => 'PostController@store',

]);
```

`The JQuery:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: "{{ url('/post') }}",
              method: 'post',
              data: {
                 content: jQuery('#content').val()
              },
              success: function(result){
                 console.log(result);
              }});
           });
        });

</script>
```

Can someone please help me with this?  Please explain to me which part of the code is wrong and what I can do to avoid making the same mistake again.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So what happend in your code you show the code but dont say which part you have error . your page is reloading?

Comment: No, i just click the button and it does nothing. I don’t know where is the error...

Comment: instead of  jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click do jQuery('#myForm').submit
and check. your code is fine . you should check other things try and check in console 
and below that code write console.log('hi'); to track which part of code doesnt run

Comment: F12 on chrome and check XHR request tab for what happen ?

Comment: But the submit button has the id of (#ajaxSubmit) and that should do the work as I know...

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-md-2" id="ajaxSubmit" type="button">Post</button>` Then remove ` e.preventDefault();` is does't necessory

Comment: POST http://hackerbounty.test/post 419 (unknown status)
send @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ news:1689
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was the following one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
           $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: "{{ url('/post') }}",
              method: 'post',
              data: {
                 _token: '{{csrf_token()}}', <-- ADD THIS LINE!
                 content: jQuery('#content').val()
              },
              success: function(result){
                 console.log(result);
              }});
           });
        });

</script>
```